# A good program to make Live USB?

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu, wine, live-usb

I have a few distros ISOs and I want to test them in a Live flash drive. They are Arch Linux, Damn Small Linux, Linux Lite, Porteus, Lubuntu 15.04 and Ubuntu 14.10. I can use Boot Disk Creator (default in Lubuntu) to create Lubuntu and Ubuntu Live USBs, but it does not work with other distros. I tried Universal USB Creator with Wine, but it doees not work properly. I searched and searched but I am not able to find a completely Ubuntu-supported creator, only Windows and Mac ones. Could you recommend me some programs? If possible, a .DEB file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unetbootin", install from your repos!